# Vite is ignoring compiler errors until the file is used at runtime

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, vite

For some reason, Vite is letting me log in to my app and do whatever, until I navigate to a page that makes use of the file with the compilation error.
At that point, it refuses to render and throws the error in the console.

I also do not see the errors in the terminal output from Vite.
However, my linter *and* the problems tab in Visual Studio Code both see the error.

[image]

How can I fix Vite to revert back to the default behaviour where the entire app must compile and only then the website renders?

Comment: Do you have a `env.development` file in your root folder? If so what are the contents? You may have `ESLINT_NO_DEV_ERRORS=true` wherein ESLint errors are converted to warnings during development.

Comment: I dont have  env.development file actually. 
Also the flag ESLINT_NO_DEV_ERRORS doesnt show up anywhere in my repo

Comment: Could you provide the code or the full web app files?

Comment: Have a look at https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#transpile-only and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72545700/vue-3-vite-typescript-dev-build-not-picking-up-ts-errors)

Comment: @Moritz Ringler
add your comment as a response, i managed to fix my problem but i cant give you the bounty if the comments

Comment: @IvanAmbla Oh, that's nice, I'll add an answer

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76480836/edit). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Vite does not do any type checking, and in watch mode, it only processes changed files. So any error that does not break transpilation of the changed files will not be picked up. This is by design, you can read up on it and how to enable additional analysis/type checking [in the docs](https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#transpile-only).

In short:

- run a parallel task doing checks, i.e. for typescript: `tsc --noEmit --watch`
- use a plugin like [vite-plugin-checker](https://github.com/fi3ework/vite-plugin-checker), which integrates running a checker into Vite's build process, showing you an error report along with the build output

Note that Vite will still build the faulty code unless you write your commands to break, i.e. something like

```
tsc --noEmit && npm run build
```

I am pretty happy with the plugin, there is a similar, Vue-specific question with [a great answer showing how to setup the plugin for typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76020900/4883195)

Answer (score 3):

Vite is a building tool. It won’t do type checking.
You have to run `tsc` with `noEmit` as `true` for that:

**Approach 1:**

Here is how my project is set up:

#### File *[package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json/)*:

```javascript
{
  .....
  "scripts": {
    .....
    "build": "tsc && vite build"
  },
  .....
}
```

#### File *tsconfig.json*

```javascript
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    .....
    "noEmit": true,
    .....
  },
  .....
}
```

Then to build, I run

```
npm run build
```

**Approach 2:**

There are people who have made Vite do type checking using a plugin, so you can go that route too.

```
npm i vite-plugin-checker
```

#### File *package.json*

```javascript
{
  .....
  "scripts": {
    .....
    "build": "vite build"
  },
  .....
}
```

#### File *vite.config.ts*

```javascript
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import checker from 'vite-plugin-checker';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    checker({
      typescript: true,
    }),
    .....
  ],
});
```

Then to build, I run

```
npm run build
```

Comment: FI: Like HTML, (single) newlines do not render on this platform.